# use lib with if pragma in perl

Tags: perl

In perl, we can do:

> use lib LIST;

to include a list of paths in @INC. Similarly, we can do:

> use if CONDITION, MODULE => ARGUMENTS;

to include a module conditionally.

Is it possible to do a mix of both, something like

> use lib if CONDITION, LIST;

to include a list of paths conditionally. This doesn't seem to work.

Edit:
Sorry, but I can't still get it working. This is how I am doing but its not working. Can you please suggest what is wrong?

```
use Data::Dumper;

BEGIN {
    my $env=$ENV{'ENV'};
    use if $env eq 'OLD', lib => '/home/vivek/OLD';
    use if $env eq 'NEW', lib => '/home/vivek/NEW';
}

print Dumper \@INC;
```

Comment: Your condition has to be resolvable at compile time.

Comment: I see that it works if instead of assigning $ENV{'ENV'} to a variable and then using it, I instead use $ENV{'ENV'} directly. But can't $env be calculated in the BEGIN block.

Comment: Your example won’t work. The assignment `my $env = ...` would run after the `use if`.  The `use if` goes first. You would have to have a wholly enclosed `BEGIN` block that assigned to a non-my variable, and then outside and below that block, have your `use if` which involves said variable.

Comment: @Vivek: it is not working as it is because you have a scoping problem. It is misleading to put `use` statements inside a `BEGIN` block because the compiler implements them as a separate `BEGIN` block of their own. That means that `$env` is out of scope at the point of the `use` statements and will be evaluated as `undef`. Simply use a package `our` variable and all will be well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) is a separate module (strictly a *pragma*) that takes the rest of the line as parameters. [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) is also a separate pragma. Take a look at the documented syntax `use if CONDITION, MODULE => ARGUMENTS` and you will see that what you should be writing is

```
use if CONDITION, lib => LIST;
```

which works fine.

Comment: People are always forgetting that the condition can only involve compile-time expressions.

Comment: @tchrist - the expression could be simply a variable computed in a `BEGIN{}` block, correct?

Comment: The *CONDITION* can be anything that is available at the relevant point in the compilation, so anything in a preceding `BEGIN` block including package variables and subroutines. (Note that such a subroutine obviously must also have any dependencies available at the time it is called.)